# Session storage return null in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

In my asp.net core web api 3.1 application I have tried to add session state, but it always returns null.
In the application I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session(2.2.0).

I also added the following code in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
   options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
   options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

and

```
app.UseSession();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

in the middleware pipeline.

I also added the following code as Session Extension

```
public static class SessionHelper
{

    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
Finally, I Set session data
SessionHelper.Set<User>(HttpContext.Session, "user", userInfo);
and tried to get as
SessionHelper.Get<User>(HttpContext.Session, "user");
```

But I am getting null always while getting session value.

Comment: When calling `Set<User>`, can you find the cookie `.AspNetCore.Session` in dev tools? If no, you could disable the cookie in your browser. It can also be intercepted by secruity policy.  And did you test it in the same client?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I didn't find cookies in dev tools, and it's not working as expected. It works fine within the same function where I set the session. when I call it in a different function or another controller then it is not working.

Comment: in your chrome, open *setting-> advanced ->privacy settings and security ->cookie and other website data*. Check whther the cookie is disabled. Besides this, you can access it through other browsers.

Comment: I checked in other browsers like firefox as well as chrome, but I didn't find cookies anywhere in dev tools. Cookies is also enabled in my chrome browser.